# How to write XPATH for element that is not included in dom?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation

I want to write the XPATH for the element thats is added by an extension in chrome, using selenium python and want to perform actions on it

when i specify the only classname in the inspect it shows the element, but when i say the class contains this class it doesnt show because its not part of dom, help me solve it

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to load those extensions in your webdriver.

For python:

```
chop = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chop.add_extension(EXTENSION_PATH)

# create new Chrome driver object with Chrome extension

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chop)
```

source: https://www.browserstack.com/guide/test-chrome-extensions-in-selenium